# Ext JS 4 отправить пост запрос

Tags: post, extjs

хочу отправить обычный пост запрос на страницу:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://localhost/test/index.php',
params  : {
   prm: 'test'
},
success: function() {
    alert('ok');
},
failure: function() {
    alert('error');
}
```

});

срабатывает failure, я не пойму. это значит что он вообще не отправляется или отправляется, но на другом конце его не понимают?

и в чем предположительно может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде все правильно, и если адрес http://localhost/test/index.php действительно функционирует, то  могу предположить, что POST-запросы не проходят. Случайно не IIS используете в качестве сервера? 
Дополнительно по Ajax-запросам в ExtJS можете посмотреть тут - [AJAX в ExtJS 4](http://metanit.com/web/extjs/9.1.php)